# Cancel an IAP subscription

Tags: codenameone, cancellation, in-app-subscription

IAP was implemented in my application. I followed Steve Hannah's blog post [Auto-Renewing Subscriptions in iOS and Android](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/autorenewing-subscriptions-in-ios-and-android.html).

There are full-price and discounted subscriptions in the application. When starting a discount subscription, the full-price subscription must be closed. Can this be solved programmatically in the application?

THX.
Péter

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't cancel a subscription programmatically and can't re-initiate a subscription without user interaction. I think Apple/Google might have a "trial" period in their web UIs that allow you to define an SKU that has a discount in the initial period.

Comment: Make sense, but any references? What if user violates the terms of conditions?

Comment: You can block them manually and I think you can cancel their subscription via the web UI but programmatically it's a bit problematic especially on iOS. I think Google supports canceling but Apple doesn't (if I recall correctly)